# inline asm - how to read and set cpsr

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly, keil

I'm trying to read `cpsr` and set `cpsr` with these function. however these functions works fine in **eclipse** but i have problem using them in `keil uvision 4`.

```
static inline unsigned __get_cpsr(void)
{
    unsigned long retval;
    asm volatile (" mrs %0, cpsr" : "=r" (retval) :  );
    return retval;
}

static inline void __set_cpsr(unsigned val)
{
    asm volatile (" msr cpsr, %0":  :"r" (val));
}
```

and i get this error:

```
error:  #65: expected a ";"
error:  #20: identifier "asm" is undefined
```

so i used **`__inline`** and **`__asm`** and now i get this error:

```
source\main.c(94): error:  #18: expected a ")"
source\main.c(94): error:  #18: expected a ")"
```

Any idea on how to fix it? or what is the steps to move these functions in a separate `asm file` which seems to be a solution, but unfortunatly i'm not familiar with assembly very much

Comment: You seem to be ending the first asm piece with a `:`, could that be the problem?

Comment: @MicroVirus i dont think so. because that means:  
`asm volatile (" mrs %0, cpsr":"=r" (retval): /* no inputs */ );`      and   
   `asm volatile (" msr cpsr, %0": /* no outputs */ :"r" (val));`

Comment: I believe you have 2 problems.  1) gcc's asm command uses att syntax by default, not intel.  So unless you are using the -masm option, "msr cpsr, %0", means move cpsr to %0, which I believe is the opposite of what you intend.  2) This syntax for asm only works in gcc.  Whatever "keil uvision" uses for compiling, it doesn't appear to be gcc.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd thanks for your helpful comment part-1. And for the second part, i think that's the correct way as it says [**here**](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasmref/armasmref_cihibbbh.htm) and [**here**](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasmref/armasmref_cihjcedb.htm)

Comment: @DavidWohlferd ARM assembly syntax doesn't know about AT&T/Intel style - GCC / GNU asm uses the "standard" there, and that, amongst other things, means the argument ordering is `target, src`. oysan, your code should do, http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.11/include/asm-arm/system.h#L286 uses the same - can you give a larger sample ?

Comment: @FrahkH. Somehow I got this confused with the x86 rdmsr. Oops. Moving on, I'd like to see what's on line 94 in main.c.  And as a simple test, what happens if you compile asm("":);  If (as I expect) this also fails to compile unless you remove the colon, we need to know exactly what compiler (and version) you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions Keil uVision usually comes with its own compiler and assembler (ARMCC 5). The assembly format of the ARMCC 5 assembler is different to that of the GCC assembler.

You will need to look into the differences.

Using ARMCC 6 with the newer Keil should fix that issue as AMRCC 6 uses the same assembly format as GCC.

Though if you need to use it in ARMCC 5, then from https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showthread/lpc2000/7010-1.php the following should work:

```
static inline unsigned __get_cpsr(void)
{
    __asm { MRS R0, CPSR }
}

static inline void __set_cpsr(unsigned val)
{
    __asm { MSR CPSR_cxfs, R0 }
}
```

I have not looked into why `cxfs` was added. Could likely just use `CPSR`.

In C, not C++, the following should also work:

```
static inline unsigned __get_CPSR(void)
{
    register unsigned regCPSR     __asm("cpsr");
    return(regCPSR);
}

static inline unsigned __set_CPSR(void)
{
    register unsigned regCPSR     __asm("cpsr");
    return(regCPSR);
}
```

https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359125006491.htm

C++ (at least from 17) ignores the register keyword, which seems to necessitate using assembly. Which is less than ideal.

Comment: Note that in actual GCC (and clang), the only supported use of `register ... asm("regname")` locals is to make an `"r"` or `"=r"` constraint choose a certain register for an Extended Asm statement (`asm("" : outputs : inputs : clobbers)`).  register ... asm as a way to read a register used to be documented, and may still happen to work in GCC, but is no longer supported.  (In GCC, documented = supported).   https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html